# Binding to RelativeSource TemplatedParent does not work within ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to port a Silverlight application to Metro, and have found that within my ControlTemplate setting my binding to `{Binding PropertyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` does not appear to work, however `{TemplateBinding PropertyName}` does.

Both of these work within my Silverlight application, however I need to use the RelativeSource syntax to allow the usage of `Mode=TwoWay`.

What do I need to do to use TwoWay bindings inside a ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building your own control - you can define template parts and retrieve them by calling GetTemplateChild() in your OnApplyTemplate() override - then just update properties manually instead of relying on bindings. If you are just retemplating existing controls - maybe you could subclass them first or create attached dependency property/[behaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) that take care of the binding.

Comment: I am attempting to share the codebase of the control logic between SL5, WP7 and Metro so was attempting to keep anything UI related within the ControlTemplate. That said, I have tried as you suggested and set up the Binding in my OnApplyTemplate, however TwoWay binding to ListBox.SelectedItemProperty doesn't appear to be working and isn't firing my PropertyChangedCallback. Maybe this is more an issue with the ListBox control than anything else.

Comment: Scrub that, I tried to replicate this in a new application containing just a custom ContentControl and it worked. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Adding a SelectionChanged event handler to the ListBox and manually updating does work however.  I'll just have to take this to the Win8 dev camp I'm off to next week and see what they have to say!